# Parsing a JSON file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I am new to JavaScript and coding in general and I have run into an issue trying to resolve a problem with a JSON column. Los Angeles operates a very handy data portal (https://data.lacity.org/A-Safe-City/LAPD-Crime-and-Collision-Raw-Data-2014/eta5-h8qx), the endpoint of which I have been pointing to in my script.  However, the lat/long (found under location_1 column at the above link) is in the format (34.0000, -118.0000). I am attempting to make heat maps using this crime data but I need the lat/long values individually to assign as parameters for the library I am attempting to use.  Can someone show me how I can separate those values and assign them to individual variables? Here is an excerpt from the script I am borrowing but I would be happy to show the entire thing if you all think it would help.

```
//let Socrata do the sorting:
http://data.lacity.org/resource/eta5-h8qx.json
var sodaUrl = "http://data.lacity.org/resource/eta5-h8qx.json?crm_cd=330"

//get json from the Socrata API
$.getJSON( sodaUrl, function( rawData ) {
var goodData = [];
for(var i=0;i<rawData.length;i++){
rawData[i].value = 0;
rawData[i].fresh=true;

if(rawData[i].location_1) {
  rawData[i].lat = parseFloat(rawData[i].location_1.latitude);
  rawData[i].lng = parseFloat(rawData[i].location_1.longitude);
}
rawData[i].date = new Date(rawData[i].date_occ + "-04:00");
if(rawData[i].location_1) {
if (rawData[i].location_1.latitude && rawData[i].location_1.longitude) {
goodData.push(rawData[i]);
};
};
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and I am happy to be more explicit if I have done poorly thus far.

Edit: here is the whole HTML document. When I try to preview in Dreamweaver I only get the basemap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>PGC Crime Heatmap Test</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<style>
body {
margin:0; padding:0;
color:#fff;
font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
}
#map {
position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%;
}
#titleBox {
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 800px;
background: #666;
border-radius: 10px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 2px solid #AFAFAF;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 46px;
text-align: center;
}
#chartBox {
position:absolute;
height:100px;
width:800px;
background:#666;
border-radius:10px;
right:0;
left:0;
bottom:20px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 2px solid #AFAFAF;
}
svg text {
fill: #fff;
}
svg line {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1px;
}
svg .domain {
stroke: #fff;
fill: none;
}
svg rect {
fill: #00AEF7;
opacity: .4;
stroke: #FFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src='heatmap.js'></script>
<script src='leaflet-heatmap.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'map'></div>
<div id = 'titleBox'>
Zip Code 11201 Vehicle Collisions Animated Heatmap (September 1 - Now)
</div>
<div id = 'chartBox'></div>
<!-- Example data. -->
<script>
//heatmap.js config
var cfg = {
// radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small radius is intended)
// if scaleRadius is false it will be the constant radius used in pixels
"radius": .001,
"maxOpacity": 1,
// scales the radius based on map zoom
"scaleRadius": true,
// if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
// if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries
// (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
"useLocalExtrema": false,
// which field name in your data represents the latitude - default "lat"
//latField: 'latitude',
// which field name in your data represents the longitude - default "lng"
//lngField: 'longitude',
// which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
valueField: 'value'
};
var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);
var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/cwhong.map-hziyh867/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
attribution: "<a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/' target='_blank'>&copy; Mapbox &copy; OpenStreetMap</a> <a class='mapbox-improve-map' href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a>",
maxZoom: 18
}
);
//setup map and add layers
var map = new L.Map('map', {
center: new L.LatLng(34.0224, -118.2870),
zoom: 14,
layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
});

//let Socrata do the sorting:
http://data.lacity.org/resource/eta5-h8qx.json
var sodaUrl = "http://data.lacity.org/resource/eta5-h8qx.json?crm_cd=330"

//get json from the Socrata API
$.getJSON( sodaUrl, function( rawData ) {
var goodData = [];
for(var i=0;i<rawData.length;i++){
rawData[i].value = 0;
rawData[i].fresh=true;

if(rawData[i].location_1) {
  rawData[i].lat = parseFloat(rawData[i].location_1.latitude);
  rawData[i].lng = parseFloat(rawData[i].location_1.longitude);
}
rawData[i].date = new Date(rawData[i].date_occ + "-04:00");
if(rawData[i].location_1) {
if (rawData[i].location_1.latitude && rawData[i].location_1.longitude) {
goodData.push(rawData[i]);
};
};
};
console.log(goodData);

var nextDate = new Date(goodData[0].date);
console.log("first nextDate: " + nextDate);

//initilaize variables for the D3 chart
var countArray = [],
svg,
day,
x,
y,
margin,
height,
width,
intervalCounter = 10,
index = 0,
lastDate,
data = {
max:15,
min:0,
data:[]
};
initializeChart();

//iterate
setInterval(function () {
//iterates 10 times for each day
if (intervalCounter == 10){
intervalCounter = 0;
getAnotherDay();
} else {
intervalCounter++;
}
//create new array for live points, push it to the map
var newData = [];
for(var j=0;j<data.data.length;j++) {
var point = data.data[j];
if(point.value >= 10) {
point.fresh = false;
}
//fade in fresh points, fade out unfresh points
if(point.fresh) {
point.value = point.value + .8;
} else {
point.value = point.value - .1;
}
if(point.value > 0) {
newData.push(data.data[j]);
}
}
data.data = newData;
heatmapLayer.setData(data);

//update the chart
day = svg.selectAll(".day")
.data(countArray)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "day")
.attr("transform", function (d) {
//var yesterday = new Date(d.date);
//yesterday = yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1)
return "translate(" + x(d.date) + ",0)";
})
.append("rect")
.attr("width", 28)
.attr("y", function (d) {
return height - y(d.count);
})
.attr("height", function (d) {
return y(d.count);
})
.attr("class", function (d) {
return (d.date);
})
}, 100);

function getAnotherDay() {
nextDate = new Date(nextDate.setHours(24,0,0,0));
var todayCounter = 0;
//iterate over goodData, push today's events to data.data
for (;;index++) {
var thisDate = goodData[index].date;
console.log(thisDate + nextDate);
if(thisDate.getTime() < nextDate.getTime()) {
data.data.push(goodData[index]);
todayCounter++;
lastDate = thisDate;
} else {
//Still need to increment lastDate if there is no data
if(todayCounter == 0) {
console.log(lastDate);
lastDate = lastDate.getDate() - 1;
}
var todayCount = {
date:lastDate,
count:todayCounter
};
countArray.push(todayCount);
break;
}
}
}
//sets margins and axes for the D3 chart. Borrowed from Chris Metcalf's example on dev.socrata.com
function initializeChart() {
// Set our margins
margin = {
top: 20,
right: 20,
bottom: 30,
left: 60
},
width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// Our X scale
x = d3.time.scale()
.domain([new Date(goodData[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(goodData[goodData.length - 1].date), 1)])
.rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right])
//.ticks(d3.time.day, 1);
// Our Y scale
y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,100])
.rangeRound([height, 0]);
// Our color bands
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#308fef", "#5fa9f3", "#1176db"]);
// Use our X scale to set a bottom axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");
// Same for our left axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickValues([0,50,100]);
// Add our chart to the #chart div
svg = d3.select("#chartBox").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should function exactly like this site, I am merely using a different dataportal and mine is centered on LA.  http://chriswhong.github.io/nyc-heatmap/

Comment: how is this code not doing what you want? Seems to grab the data, loop through it and build a `goodData` array.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is as you havent said what exactly is wrong, but if you are wanting to use `goodData` outside the getJSON callback you will need to use a global variable or pass `goodData` to another function that will use it

Comment: I dunno, I feel like this should be a fairly simple fix because the entire code is written. The only differences are the API endpoint, the column names he pulls his data from, and the center point of the map. Everything else should be the exact same. Again, I am very new to coding. I am a geographer not a developer heh! I am only seeing a basemap though and nothing else.

Comment: What you are looking for is there clear as day. The issue you have I think is understanding the syntax of the language to make it work for you and nobody is going to teach you that in one sitting. You should provide both API endpoint examples, explain that you're not a developer, show that you've done everything in your power to get the job done then simply ask for assistance. You've done most of this so far but if you're willing to provide the other endpoint I'll definitely see what I can do. This forum is pretty much for developers only though and not for giving handouts, thus few responses.

Comment: Ahh, I just figured I am missing something very obvious here. Is there another forum I can look to for future issues? I am trying to get my hands dirty with this but I have to dedicate time to my degree first. The endpoint he is using is this  https://data.cityofnewyork.us/NYC-BigApps/NYPD-Motor-Vehicle-Collisions/h9gi-nx95.  I really appreciate any help, I definitely want to understand what is going on and I thought I could with the code already written but I guess not!